# Reading huge images from SD CARD and save them resized (out of memory!)

Tags: android, image, bitmap, out-of-memory

I'm trying to read images from the SD CARD and save them in my custom directory resized to 1024 pixels, but always I got an OutOfMemory. I've tried most of examples I found here in stackoverflow about that "out of memory" staff...

I was asking me how the Galería App manage images 4000 pixels so easily???

Thanks.
David.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was asking me how the Galería App manage images 4000 pixels so
>   easily?

It uses [`BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) in combination with the decoding methods of [`BitmapFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) to load a size-reduced thumbnail from the disk. It also tiles images and only load a certain part of an image if it is zoomed.

Comment: Hi alextsc, I also tried the inSampleSize, but even with a 8 I got an out of memory. I'm trying to read an 4000 pixels image (about 2Mb). I know I's too much, but Galerry manage them easily...
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you post your code? 4000x4000 px with sample size 8 should be a 500x500 px image loaded, that's just under 1 MB in memory. Which should be small enough.

Comment: This is my code:

BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bounds.inSampleSize = 8;
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo.getPath(), bounds);

And I got an out of memory then the decodeFile is called...

Comment: Looks ok. Do you use many bitmaps at once (and not just the one)? Also try [profiling](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/memory-management-for-android-apps.html) your memory usage and check if you use too much

Comment: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4019c760)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:493)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:299)
at dreamflow.portfolio4android.comp.ImageShowerComp.showPhoto(ImageShowerComp.java:207)
at dreamflow.portfolio4android.LauncherFragment.imageSelected(LauncherFragment.java:231)
at dreamflow.portfolio4android.comp.PictureManagerComp$1.onClick(PictureManagerComp.java:136)

Comment: Ok, I thing I found the thing. If I create a new clean project and I read the image with a 4 sample size is working. So I have some problem about the memory in my App.
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code. Hope this would help.

Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);

```
    int orig_width = bMap.getWidth();
    int orig_height = bMap.getHeight();
    int aspect = orig_width / orig_height;

    float aspectRatio = orig_width / orig_height;

    int new_height = (int) (orig_height / (aspectRatio));
    int new_width = (int) ((orig_width * aspectRatio)/2);

    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap, new_height, new_width, true);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    scaled.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos); 
    byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
    options.inSampleSize = 5; 

    File sdImageMainDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null; 
    String tempFile = "tempImage"; 
    int quality = 50; 

    Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata, 0,bitmapdata.length);

    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory.toString() +"/" + tempFile + ".jpg");
        BufferedOutputStream bosBufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream); 

        myImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, bosBufferedOutputStream); 
        bosBufferedOutputStream.flush();
        bosBufferedOutputStream.close(); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

On Android, mobile application is limited in memory, so nobody would ever think of loading such a huge `Bitmap` like that (4000px) to memory. 
Just some tips for handling this situation:

1. Resize image to fit screen display (fitting view display is better)
2. Reduce quality to an acceptable level (whereas users' eyes cannot feel the differences, maybe)
3. Not displaying too much `Bitmap` images at the same time.
4. Avoiding the use of `getPixel()` and `setPixel` too much, it would lead to really really bad performance. Use `getPixels()` and `setPixels()` instead.
5. After done using `Bitmap`, `recycle()` it to release memory (GC knows what to do at this point).
6. Don't try to create so many references to `Bitmap` objects, you'd kill yourself afterward!!!

Comment: Sorry, I'm programming in honeycomb.

Answer (score 0):

send:

```
                        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
                    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true; 
                    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o); 

                    int REQUIRED_SIZE = 640; 
                    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight; 
                    int scale = 1; 
                    while(true) { 
                        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE) break; 
                        width_tmp /= 2; 
                        height_tmp /= 2; 
                        scale *= 2; 
                    } 

                    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
                    o2.inSampleSize = scale; 
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2); 

                    ByteArrayOutputStream bs2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bs2);
                    getIntent().putExtra("byte_picture", bs2.toByteArray());
```

recive:

```
Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data.getByteArrayExtra("byte_picture"),0,data.getByteArrayExtra("byte_picture").length);
```